# StopAsync not called in worker service in .net core 3 when running as Windows service

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, background-service

wonder if you guys have encountered this before. I wanted to have grpc server+web api running as windows service as it's meant for a long runningprocess. The web API is basically just for runtime monitoring of internal states.. So I created a new grpc service (.net core 3), and add in the worker class, and add the controller etc..  and used the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices nuget package to enable Windows service. I used "sc create  binpath=  start= auto" to install it, then used "sc start " to start it.. observing the log file, I can see it's started, accessing the swagger page, I can see it's running fine.

I'm logging something to the log file when the StartAsync and StopAsync are called in the worker class and I can see that when the service starts, StartAsync is called, as it should be.

Now the funny thing is this, when the system is restarted, I don't see StopAsync being called..

in DOS, if I used dotnet .exe to run it, StartAsync is called, pressing CTRL+C to stop it, StopAsync is called.. but why is StopAsync not called when it's running as windows service and system is restarted? is this a bug in the windwos service nuget package itself? or am I missing something here?

Funny thing is, in Startup class, I even used IHostApplicationLifetime to intercept the ApplicationStarting, ApplicationStopping, but again, starting is called, but stopping is not called.. why?

can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

nice folks at .net core team already knew of this issue and will address it in .net core 5.0. refer here: https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/pull/2705

ETA end of 2020.

Comment: What the heck! I wasted a good part of the evening grappling with this error :(